# Right way to encode a video when uploading to facebook with iOS FBSDK v4 (multipart/form-data)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

first: It looks like there are two ways to upload a video to facebook with a GraphRequest. One that uses the "file_url" parameter. You provide an URL and facebook downloads the video file from an external server. That works wonderful like this:

```
let params = [
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "file_url": "http://example.com/videofile.mp4"
]

let rq = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "POST")

rq.startWithCompletionHandler { (conn, result, error) -> Void in
    // handle error etc..
}
```

Facebook loads the file from my server an the video appears on my timeline.

The other method is to upload the video direct with the request using the "source" parameter. That should kinda looks like this:

```
let videoURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testvideo", ofType: "mp4")!)
let rawData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)!

let params = [
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "source": rawData
]
```

However this fails with this error message:

```
The video you're trying to upload is in a format that isn't supported. Please try again with a video in a supported format.
```

Taking a look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/video) it looks like the video data has to be encoded in "multipart/form-data". The docu even provides a link to [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

However how to do this is still a mystery for me. I tried lots of combinations of making a formdata string with the binary video data in it like:

```
var s = ""
s += "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n\r\n"
s += "--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n"
s += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"

let p = "--XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX--"

let data = NSMutableData()
data.appendData(s.asUTF8Data())
data.appendData(rawData)
data.appendData(p.asUTF8Data())

let params = [
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "source": data
]
```

and other combinations with

```
s += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"
s += "Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n"
```

But without success. I always get the same error message:

```
The video you're trying to upload is in a format that isn't supported. Please try again with a video in a supported format.
```

So how to wrap a video file in form-data?

Just in case:
No unfortunately I can't use the video sharing function that is already provided in FBSDK v4.

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this? I am having a hard time finding the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

After getting stuck for three day, finally I'm able to get the solution for this error '**The video you're trying to upload is in a format that isn't supported. Please try again with a video in a supported format.**
' when uploading from local file. Remember the rules is ***Do not include "source" or "file_url" in the request parameters even though the FB documentation says so.***
Below is my working code:

```
func uploadVideoToWall() {
    var videoData: NSData
    guard let localVideoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "overthinking", ofType: "mp4") else {
        print("local video not found")
        return
    }
    print("local video path: \(localVideoPath)")
    let localPathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: localVideoPath, isDirectory: false)
    print("absolute string: \(localPathURL.absoluteString)")

    do {
        videoData = try NSData(contentsOf: localPathURL)
        var strDesc : String
        strDesc = " testing upload from test app 2"
        //Do no include "source" or "file_url" in the request parameters even though the FB documentation says so.
        let videoObject: [String : Any] = ["contentType": "multipart/form-data", "title": "Testing yoooo", "description": strDesc, localPathURL.absoluteString: videoData]
        //self.view!.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        let uploadVideoRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: videoObject, httpMethod: "POST")
        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
        connection.delegate = self
        connection.add(uploadVideoRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")

            }
            else {
                print("Success")
            }
        })
        connection.start()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found an example on how to do this using the FB Graph APi, in this project:
https://github.com/brynbellomy/SEBeamMeUpScotty

Relevant parameters are:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: self.videoURL];              NSMutableDictionary *params = @{@"video.mp4":   videoData,
                                @"contentType": @"video/quicktime",
                                @"title":       @"Money Money Video Maker",
                                @"description": @"", }.mutableCopy;
```